# Play audiofile using android ndk

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

So im trying to make app which plays for example "birds.mp3" audio file whenever togglebutton is enabled and it stops the audio when its disabled. Im trying to make this with android ndk for practice and ive been trying to use AAudio API because its look very simple to use, but i cant figure out how to make it work.

Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // The toggle is enabled

                    StartAudio();
                } else {
                    // The toggle is disabled

                    StopAudio();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public native String StartAudio();
    public native String StopAudio();


}
```

C++ file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <SLES/OpenSLES_Android.h>
#include <aaudio/AAudio.h>
#include <vector>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL

Java_com_example_boman_ndk_MainActivity_StartAudio( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {

    AAudioStreamBuilder *builder;
    aaudio_result_t result = AAudio_createStreamBuilder(&builder);

    if(builder != nullptr) {
        AAudioStream* stream = nullptr;
        result = AAudioStreamBuilder_openStream(builder, &stream);

        if(result == AAUDIO_OK && stream != nullptr) {

        }

        AAudioStreamBuilder_delete(builder);
    }
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_k2972_ndk_AudioActivity_StopAudio( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj ) {
// Stop Audio




}
```

So i get stuck here. i create the stream but i dont know how i should use it. How i make it process my audiofile. So if someone could explain this to me i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with

```
#include <media/NdkMediaCodec.h>
#include <media/NdkMediaExtractor.h>
```

And follow the [official sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-codec). See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/VDxqBTrF9RY/iZ_ZoE0pBwAJ.